# Sorting a datatable by a column that contains part numbers and part letters

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a datatable and I need to be able to sort either asc or desc by the jobcode column. Unfortunately the column field values contain both numbers and letters like this.

HD1233
HD12333
PG2839
TP9383

I need to extract the numbers, sort numerically and then put it back. So the above would look like this in the output.

HD1233
PG2839
TP9383
HD12333

I have a piece of code which does some sort of sort which is like this ...

```
        Dim dtOut As DataTable = Nothing
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = Convert.ToString("jobcode" & Convert.ToString(" ")) &    drpAscorDesc.SelectedItem.Text
        dtOut = dt.DefaultView.ToTable()
```

Im just unable to do it properly without the letters. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add another column of type Integer to your DataTable.
2. Iterate through all DataRows, put values into new column based on job codes in these datarows (read value -> delete all non-numeric characters -> Int32.TryParse()).
3. Sort by new column.